# Cannot use chef provisioning in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I created a basic vagrant box and config provisioning as below

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "apache2"
    chef.json = { :apache => { :default_site_enabled => true } }
end
```

I also add cookbook to my project

```
git submodule add https://github.com/svanzoest-cookbooks/apache2/ cookbooks/apache2
```

But when I run vagrant provision, I get this

```
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:52+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance     to converge...
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:52+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.1.2 ***
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:52+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1130
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[apache2]"] from CLI options
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[apache2]]
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [apache2]
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for precise32
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] INFO: Start handlers   complete.
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] ERROR: Running exception  handlers
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook iptables not found. If you're loading iptables from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:55:54+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Maybe iptables cookbook is required, so I add it. And then I get this message

```
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:58:32+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:58:32+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook logrotate not found. If you're loading logrotate from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your 
==> default: [2015-03-26T14:58:32+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

logrotate cookbook is required?
Why does it continuously require cookbook? What is metadata here? 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: look ito the apache3 cookbook, there's a metadata.rb file with entries inside like `depends "iptables"` and `depends "logrotate"` and so on, each cookbook in depends will have it's own metadata.rb file with depends entry. You have to get the complete stack, a too like berkshelf can help at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookbooks can have dependencies to other cookbooks. This allows them to rely on functionality provided by these other cookbooks.

In your case, your apache2 cookbook depends on the `iptables` and the `logrotate` cookbooks. You can check this in each cookbook's `metadata.rb` file. In case of your apache2 cookbook, you can find the `metadata.rb` file [on GitHub](https://github.com/svanzoest-cookbooks/apache2/blob/fd1aa58131e5a0dcc30e73964673ec96f650cd3c/metadata.rb#L10-L11).

Note that cookbooks can also have recursive dependencies, i.e. they can have further dependencies which must all be fulfilled. Because if this, it is often recommended to manage your cookbooks with a tool like [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) or [Librarian](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef) which can download all cookbook dependencies automatically and consistent.